# suggestion for installed apps in google search bar

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spOoe.png)How to add multiple names to an app and which will work in google search bar in android like if i have an app doctor_App and i want the google search bar should show the installed app suggestion by the name like medicine,hospital. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spOoe.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of which "google search bar" you are referring to?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN5Nr.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spOoe.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLKTT.png